# Cypress-Cucumber executing tags in a script

Tags: cypress

Im trying to execute a simple cypress test via Scripts inside the package.json file, however everytime I run the script I get an error.

When I execute via command line:

```
npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@Delete'
```

the test with the @Delete tag works

Inside my package.json file the script is wrote exactly the same:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test:tag": "npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@Delete'"
  },
```

When I execute via command line:

```
npm run test:tag
```

I see the below error:
Using cypress.json configuration:
Spec files:  cypress/integration/**/*.feature
No matching tags found

Comment: can you share your cypress.json file ?

Comment: @AlapanDas        { "testFiles": "*/.feature", "baseUrl": "myurl", "pageLoadTimeout" : 20000,"$schema": "on.cypress.io/cypress.schema.json", "retries": { "runMode": 3, "openMode": 3 } }